# How do you remove a role attribute in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

In postgres I have used the following to assign the SuperUser attribute to 'myrole':

```
ALTER ROLE myrole WITH Superuser;
```

I now want to remove the the Superuser attribute, but I can't find the correct command online or on Postgres docs, only about setting it.

Can someone let me know how it is done please?

I have tried replacing "WITH" with "DROP", "REVOKE", "REMOVE", but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As instructed in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterrole.html):

```
ALTER ROLE myrole WITH NOSUPERUSER;
```

You must be superuser, of course, to do that.